# Way to print all steps of transforming 1 to 0 in a matrix

Tags: python, path-finding, heuristics

I have this exercise in Python but i couldn't figure out yet. Imagine we have a vacuum that removes dirt from the floor in a room. This room is a matrix of 0 and 1(program allows user to insert the size); '1' means dirty and '0' means clean. The position of this vacuum is random in the matrix(i succeed to print it on the matrix with value of -1 but wish to assign it with a character like an 'X'). This vacuum can just move one step, it can move in 4 directions as blow :[image: You can see a screen shot here]

The purpose is to make the vacuum find all the number 1 and transform it to 0,  at the end we can receive a matrix of 0. I also want to print all the step/move and count each move that the vacuum does is this matrix. This transformation is random and needs to be optimized (shortest time to clean the room).

Here is my program to modify:

[image]

Thank you so much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You should start by making a list of the sequence that your code will have to execute. something like

```
1. Get a list of possible locations to move
2. Pick one options from that list
3. Execute the movement
```

So your task should be writing this three functions.

The first one can be as simple as just generating a list with up, down, left, right. You will see that you should take in account edge cases (eg: being in the top row so you cannot go up)

The second one is picking one of the options. It can be completely random, it can be a bit better by moving only to dirty tiles to move or it can be a sophisticated path optimization. Start with the easiest option: random.

The third one should update the cleaner location and update the matrix.

Now, start making this functions, make them simple and when they work try implementing more features and considering more cases.

Name your functions appropiately. `my_matrix` is not a proper name for a function that what is does is initialize your setup. You can call it `initialize` instead.

Then have a main function that initializes the problem and has a loop where it executes your sequence of functions.